# Updating ionicdb using web api?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cloud, ionic-cloud, ionic-cloud-angular

I wish to know if there is any way to update ionicdb using web api , or from a rest client tool. I know parse platform had it and firebaseDb  also has it.  But I could not find any documentation for ionic cloud db. It says how to set up in your mobile app , but not through web api. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sorry for the late answer... the docs are here: 
http://docs.ionic.io/api/endpoints/db.html
but unfortunately ionicDB is going away soon.  It looks like the Beta has run its course and they're closing it down.

I hope I'm not the one to be the bearer of bad news. :(

Comment: Thanks for the answer..and yes you are the bearer of the bad news early morning to me !! I didnt know before..I wish I could kill you.

Comment: This is the best death threat I've ever received. :)  Yeah.. I'm currently shifting everything from ionicdb to firebase.  It's never fun repeating tasks you've already completed. *sigh*